# Matching all digits from a string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract *all* numbers from a string.
C# pads large value to number E +- num.

```
Regex.Match(99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98.ToString(), @"\d+\.*\d*")
```

matches only to:

```
9.99999999999956
```

clearly rounding part of the number.

How to get all digits, 99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98

-> 9999999999999555555555555555555555555999998?

Comment: Your regexp is matching entire number, however, you probably convert this number to a numeric variable, and every numerical variable has its limits. Thats why it is being rounded probably.

Comment: Googling what's the max value of a integer. What is the maximum possible value of an integer in C# ? The maximum possible value of an integer is 2,147,483,647. And for the regex I would use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` in case you don't always have a float

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
Regex.Match("99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98", @"\d+\.*\d*");
```

[image]

Update: Try do the test

```
var    result1 = 99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98.ToString();
double result2 = 99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98;
string result3 = "99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98";
Console.WriteLine(result1); // 9.99999999999956E+40
Console.WriteLine(result2); // 9.99999999999956E+40
Console.WriteLine(result3); // 99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98
```

Comment: Do what exactly? Code seems identical.

Comment: @Fildor I use the string type directly, while you use a very large number and then convert it to a string.

Comment: I don't do anything. I just wondered what you mean by "just do this"... but now I see the difference.

Comment: @Fildor I update the answer. your code do the ".ToString()" but I no. So I mean just use string, dose not convert a lager number to string.

Answer (score 0):

The question has: `Regex.Match(99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98.ToString(), @"\d+\.*\d*")`

The `99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98` is a real literal. [This Microsoft page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) states *"The literal without suffix or with the d or D suffix is of type double"*. The page also states that values of type double have a precision of 15 to 17 decimal digits.

The `99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98.ToString()` takes that value of type double and converts it to a string.

---

The following code helps to show what is happening. Note that `number` and `numberAsString` are both declared with `var` so that the compiler will choose the type based on the assigned expression.

```
var number = 99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98;
Console.WriteLine($"number is {number} and is of type {number.GetType().ToString()}");

var numberAsString = 99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98.ToString();
Console.WriteLine($"numberAsString is '{numberAsString}' and is of type {numberAsString.GetType().ToString()} and has {numberAsString.Length} characters");

Match match = Regex.Match(99999999999995555555555555555555555559999.98.ToString(), @"\d+\.*\d*");
Console.WriteLine($"match success is {match.Success}");
Console.WriteLine($"match value is '{match.Value}' and has {match.Value.Length} characters");
```

The output from the above is:

```
number is 9.999999999999555E+40 and is of type System.Double
numberAsString is '9.999999999999555E+40' and is of type System.String and has 21 characters
match success is True
match value is '9.999999999999555' and has 17 characters
```

One of the characters in the match value is a `.` thus there are 16 decimal digits which corresponds to the precision stated above.